# Routing to other network

Tags: routing

I have a network setup like this:

```
                                          -> Clients
Internet -> GW      -> Router 1 (bridged) -> Router 2 (VPN Client, DHCP) -> Clients
            10.0.1.1   10.0.1.110            10.0.1.140
                                             / 192.168.1.1
```

The first router acts just as an AP with wireless enabled, where the clients receive IPs from the gateway. The second router acts as a VPN client and has also its own network. The idea here is to route everything thru the VPN.

How can I route traffic from the 10.0.1.0/24 network to access 192.168.1.0/24 clients? Let's say I'm a client on Router 1 with IP of 10.0.1.115 and I want to access a client with IP 192.168.1.230. Can I achieve this?

The router1 is a EasyTomato router, and it's already intercepting any DNS requests. I tried to setup a route like so:

```
Destination    Gateway       Subnet
192.168.1.0    10.0.1.140    255.255.255.0
```

but this did not yield any results (the 10.0.1.140 is the external IP of the router2). 
The Router2 is a usbtomato router.

### Why?

Behind the Router2 is a Samsung TV (with no VPN built-in), which connects to my media centre located at another location. However, I would also like to be able to stream data to the TV from the 10.0.1.0 network.

Comment: Have you disabled NAT on Router 2 so that 192.168.1.230 appears on the 10.x network with its own address rather than the router 2 10.0.1.140 address?  Your route is correct.  And you'll probably want to disable the firewall on router2 unless you have sufficient control to allow the incoming traffic.

Comment: @paul by disabling the NAT (Setting the router from Gateway to Router), broke its functionality. I "solved" the issue by connecting all clients to the Router1 network, and adding a route to the VPN subnet from router1 to router2. This means that clients on router1 can reach VPN computers without being directly connected to router2.